# Reading and writing WAVE file produces unplayable output

Tags: c#, wav

I want to add echo to wave file, in order to do so I need to open it and then save it first. I've written some methods but output file is not correct.

Testing input file size: 731 014

Output file sieze: 730 898

But the "space on disc" is the same for both files, which is 733 184

Error code or whatever it is displayed when opened: 0xc00d36c4

What can be the issue here? This looks pretty simple and yet it's not working. Here's my header, read and write methods:

```
 class WaveFile
 {
      struct WaveHeader
      {
           public byte[] RiffID;
           public uint fileSize;
           public byte[] format;

           //Wave format chunk 1
           public byte[] fmtID;
           public uint fmtSize;
           public ushort audioFormat;
           public ushort channels;
           public uint sampleRate;
           public uint byteRate;
           public ushort blockAlign; 
           public int bitsPerSample;

           //Wave format chunk 2
           public byte[] dataID;
           public uint dataSize;                            
      }

      uint samples;

      public List<short> L;
      public List<short> R;

      WaveHeader header = new WaveHeader();

      //loading file, preparation for modyfying
      public bool loadWaveFile(string filePath)
      {
           using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
           using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
           {
                // chunk 0
                header.RiffID = reader.ReadBytes(4);
                header.fileSize = reader.ReadUInt32();
                header.format = reader.ReadBytes(4);
                // chunk 1
                header.fmtID = reader.ReadBytes(4);
                header.fmtSize = reader.ReadUInt32();
                header.audioFormat = reader.ReadUInt16();
                header.channels = reader.ReadUInt16();
                header.sampleRate = reader.ReadUInt32();
                header.byteRate = reader.ReadUInt32();
                header.blockAlign = reader.ReadUInt16();
                header.bitsPerSample = reader.ReadInt16();
                // chunk 2
                header.dataID = reader.ReadBytes(4);
                header.dataSize = reader.ReadUInt32();

                // DATA is stereo
                L = new List<short>();
                R = new List<short>();

                samples = header.dataSize / header.blockAlign;
                for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
                {
                     L.Add((short)reader.ReadUInt16());
                     R.Add((short)reader.ReadUInt16());
                }
                reader.Close();
                fs.Close();
           }
           return true;
      }

      public bool addEcho(int threadsNumber, int echoesNumber, int delay, int attenuation)
      {
           return true;
      }

      public bool saveWaveFile(string savingPath)
      {
           using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@savingPath + "\\echo.wav", FileMode.Create))
           using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
           {
                //chunk 0
                writer.Write(header.RiffID);
                writer.Write(header.fileSize);
                writer.Write(header.format);
                //chunk 1
                writer.Write(header.fmtID);
                writer.Write(header.fmtSize);
                writer.Write(header.audioFormat);
                writer.Write(header.channels);
                writer.Write(header.sampleRate);
                writer.Write(header.byteRate);
                writer.Write(header.blockAlign);
                writer.Write(header.bitsPerSample);
                //chunk 2
                writer.Write(header.dataID);
                writer.Write(header.dataSize);

                for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
                {
                     writer.Write(L[i]);
                     writer.Write(R[i]);
                }
                writer.Close();
                fs.Close();
                return true;
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: use a binary diff tool to compare the two files and see why they're different

Comment: "space on disc" is irrelevant for your problem; don't be concerned with it. It is only the product of the file system's block size and the number of file system blocks your file uses.

Comment: blockalign is NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8, so you should be correct in determining number of samples = dataSize / blockAlign if it really is stereo. you're just 116 bytes short of the input file size. could encoding be the problem here > what is the value of AudioFormat? also [consult this](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/)

Comment: AudioFormat is 1, so no extra parameters unfortunately. I'm thinking about doing this another way, I'll put the whole file into byte array and modify it from 44 index, which is where the data starts. That way no bytes should be missing and modifying it won't change the header. Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find out what the issue was, but for echo purposes this class will work:

```
Class WaveFile
 {
      byte[] byteArray;

      public void loadWaveFile(string filePath)
      {
           byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
      }

      public bool addEcho(int threadsNumber, int echoesNumber, int delay, int attenuation)
      {
           return true;
      }

      public bool saveWaveFile(string savingPath)
      {
           using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@savingPath + "\\echo.wav", FileMode.Create))
           using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
           {
                writer.Write(byteArray);                   
                writer.Close();
                fs.Close();
                return true;
           }
      }
 }
```